# How-to recover previous swap partitions space?

Tags: 11.10, swap, re-installation, resize, disk-utility

After several clean re-installations of Ubuntu 11.10 on my Lenovo S12 Laptop (Intel Atom), I found I have five new swap partitions in addition to the original swap partition on 11.04.

Not only do they significantly slow down the system, each additional swap stole disk space from my root partition.  Originally 50GB, it was now down to 39GB.

I used "Disk Utility" to discover which partitions were superfluous (/dev/sd⋯, …) then edited as super·user the `/etc/fstab` file commenting out them. Then rebooted.

After reboot, I used "Disk Utility" again to delete the five superfluous partitions.

Not the question is, how do I re-size the root partition to recover the stolen space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is the same answer as [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85408/why-are-there-multiple-6-swap-partitions-after-ubuntu-clean-install).

The answer by Bruno Pereira was very helpful, but it turns out that it was incmplete, details in the way I finally fixed it.

What a can of worms this was…

First, repeated "hiccoughs" involved with installing Ubuntu 11.10 x86 replacing a 11.04 lead to repeated re-installs, much simpler than trying to "fix" them on my diminutive Lenovo S12 (Intel Atom) laptop.

- In summary, the initial install over the pretty much unused 11.04 on the Lenovo S12 11.10 Desktop using the original disk partitions and subsequent re-installs lead to the following result: five new swap partitions, all taken from the original root partition.  This resulted in an extremely long boot (obscured by lengthly non-responsive period after the Desktop presented itself on screen).  No indication was ever given that the installation was not using the original partitions, and were being modified in such an obtrusive manner.  OK, rant over.

As a result, when finally a working Unity system was achieved, I had the original swap partition 4GB, plus 5 new 2.1GB, unwanted and unneeded swap partitions, taking disk space from the already small, root partition ⋯ 20% of the root partition on my laptop.

**Note: does not apply to Wubi installations**

This is how I fixed it:

1. Identified the swap partitions using "Disk Utility".
2. Edited `/etc/fstab` to ignore these partitions, and rebooted.
3. Installed and used *gparted* (Linux disk partition manager) to drop
   the 5 superfluous, newly deprecated swap partitions.
4. Booted from live-CD to run *gparted* to resize the diminished root
   partition back to full size.
5. Surprise…! ⋯ used `grub resume >` to get *grub2* to properly boot
   Ubuntu after a failed boot.
6. Downloaded, installed and ran *grub-repair* to fix the emasculated
   *grub2*.
7. Popped down to the local pub for a few pints of Guinness. and to
   complain about the government.

Now I don't recommend doing this, because it's noisome and dangerous.  But if you're willing to try here goes my step·by·step with additional elucidations from one who has gone before.

#### Identify Disk partitions

Use *Disk Utility* to discover which partitions do what.  Open *Disk Utility* (in the usual manner (on *Unity* left mouse button the dash icon, type in **Disk Utility**, …)

Here's a screen shot of *Disk Utility* (after the superfluous swap partitions were removed)⋯

[image: Screenshot at 2011-12-06 08-16-08.png]

*Note: press **CTRL-+** one or more times to make screenshot readable in your browser, **Ctrl-0** or **Ctrl-- (minus)** to restore to normal*

In this view, the "S12 System Disc 106 GB NTFS" IS SELECTED. on my Laptop, the 5 superfluous swap partitions were shown to the left of "50 GB ext4" and beneath the "Extended 50 GB".

- To work on a partition, select (highlight) it with the mouse.
- Directly beneath the selected partition is "Device: /dev/sd⋯⋯" which identifies the partions.  Make a note of the ones to be deleted.
- To Delete the selected partition, click on the Delete at the bottom of the Window.  You cannot delete them now becasue the system is using them, more or less.

The original swap partition should be the first (4GB on mine).  The others were added to the extended partition my root was in, as 2GB each; /dev/sda5, /dev/sda6, /dev/sda7 …

If you plan to recover space, as I did for extending the shrunken `/root` partition, make sure that there is unused space around it.  Usually this means leaving only the first or last swap partition.

If the `/root` partition is in an extended partition and a to be deleted swap partition is not, this complicated extending the `/root` partition.  Can be done, though.

You'll need to make a note of the following…

- The boot disk (on mine, there was only one disk so no problem here)
- The partition the `/root` partition, and if on a seperate partition, the `/boot` partition.

  *Note: a seperate /boot partition is not standard on Ubuntu installs, and would have to have been especially set by someone.  So if you don't see one, that's OK.  More common is a separate /home partition, likewise especally set, as is the case on my laptop.  We won't have to concern ourselve with that here.*

The next section shows a way to get this information more or easily as a premptive measure.

#### preemptive boot-repair installation

You will need to be connected to the internet for this...

Download and install *Boot-repair* by opening a termina and typing…

```
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`
```

and then

```
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair`
```

Be agreeable and answer all quesstions affirmatively.

Then start *boot-repair* in the usual manner (on Unity left mouse button the dash icon, type in **boot-repair**, …)

- Agree to an update, if any
- Select "Create a Bootinfo summary..."
- Wait until a message box appears and **make a note of the URL** (`http://paste.ubuntu.com/nnnnnn/`), where nnnnnn is a big number.  You can read this document anywhere with a browser just by entering the URL.

The first paragraph of this splendid document will tell you what you need to know.  Save a copy where you can access without the computer you are fixing.

- Furthermore, in case you run into trouble here, quite likely actually, this information will be invaluable to someone assisting you.

#### edit fstab to depracate unneded swap partitions

Open a terminal in the usual manner

Type in **sudo nano -B /etc/fstab**, as an example from mine⋯

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda9 during installation
UUID=83ca52f1-0518-4992-95b3-58f1d4f58bc0 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda10 during installation
UUID=d30c8114-cc1a-49d3-8924-be46a64c5be5 none            swap    sw              0       0
# swap was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=39421e04-b191-48a1-bfef-04ad1ad77329 none            swap    sw              0       0
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=5e047822-53ed-4f2a-bd5a-b25804f41dda none            swap    sw              0       0
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=e6589d14-fb5f-4e88-89d0-b3117a5382c9 none            swap    sw              0       0
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
#UUID=71519d3c-8d4b-4e1d-a380-9d1f8d38fd04 none            swap    sw              0       0
# swap was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=43bfad50-23f1-4813-b622-fe78558f73a1 none            swap    sw              0
```

To stop the unwanted swap partitions from being used on your computer, just add a "#" to the front of the line.  Use the notes from "gparted"

So now it should look like this⋯

[image]

Save the changes with **Ctrl-O** and **Enter**, then close with **Ctrl-X**

And **reboot**.

Now the system should be faster to complete booting.

#### using gparted to free the disk

Now that the deprecated swap partitions are not in use and can be deleted by selecting each one and the the deleting them using the GUI's function.  Open *Disk Utility* (in the usual manner (on *Unity* left mouse button the dash icon, type in **Disk Utility**, …)

- To work on a partition, select (highlight) it with the mouse.
- To Delete the selected partition, click on the Delete at the bottom of the Window.  You can now delete them now becasue the system is no longer using them.

#### using liveCD to restore lost space on root partition

Freeing up the disk space gobbled up by the sulime Ubuntu installation requires booting the system from another operating system, here we choose the Ubuntu LiveCD. Same version as installed, please.

- There are other ways of doing this, feel free to use what ever makes your needle read.

Boot from the LiveCD and choose "Try Ubuntu".

*gparted* is on the LiveCD although not installed in a typical installation with Ubuntu.

Open a terminal and type in **gksu garted**.  The terminal will throw up a bunch of stuff like…

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ gksu gparted
(gksu:5791): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
(gksu:5791): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
(gksu:5791): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
(gksu:5791): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
======================
libparted : 2.3
======================
```

…but then the GParted GUI will open.  Resize the `/root` partition per GParted.

- Do not interrupt the process ⋯ *likely consequences will be dire*

When finished, close out liveCD and restart.

It's possibe it will reboot nicely but mine didn't  ~~ *cue somber music*

#### getting grub2 to work after partition resize

First we have to get Ubuntu to boot through grub2 starting at  `grub rescue >`

- first type in **ls -l** and hit **Enter**.

You should get a listing like this  `(hd0) (hd0,1) …` or `(hd0) (hd0,msdos1) …`

These correspond to the /dev/sda, /dev/sda1 … from the Boot Info Script done earlier.

- It can be tricky `hd0, hd1, hd2…` may not exactly conform to `/dev/sda, /dev/sdb/, /dev/sdc …`.
- Match up the disk and partitions, mine was (hd0) for the disk and (hd9,msdos5) for the root partition. Of course the laptop had only disk so it was easy for me.
- Further down in the Bootinfo output (`http://paste.ubuntu.com/nnnnnn/`) is where the root partition is, under "⋯ /boot/grub/menu.lst" which could be helpful.

Something like:

```
title       Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS, kernel 2.6.32-30-generic
root        (hd0,0)
```

These steps come from here/https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Rescue_Mode_.28.27.27grub_rescue.3E.27.27.29_Booting.  Good place to go if these steps don't work.

Once you have identified the grug install disk and the `/root` partition. the type in…

- **set prefix=(hd*X*,*Y*)/boot/grub**  *where as above, X=0 and Y=msdos1 (or just 1)*
- **set root=(hd*X*,*Y*)**   *as above*
- **insmod normal**  *Attempt to load the normal module*
- **normal**  *Activate the normal module. If successful, the GRUB 2 menu appears.*

If the grub boot menu appears, as it did for me, you have beat the odds, point your elbow at the ceiling and pat yourself on the back.  Then do the next step, so you don't have to do this again.

If not, go back to [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#GRUB%202%20Troubleshooting%20Preparation) and, alas, good luck.

#### repairing grub to to avoid the need for `grub rescue >` again

Finalizing the grub boot fix…

Run boot-repar again, this time you probably don't have to check for updates, and this time run "recommended repair"

#### Fini

Hope this helps.  Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gparted` to resize your root partition and take back the space that your swap partitions were taking.

It has a nice graphical interface and its as simple as dragging size arrows to move and resize partitions, no need to reformat and `gparted` will take care of all the small details involving the partitions resizing.

Boot from the Ubuntu 11.10 LiveCD, install `gparted` with by looking for it in the Ubuntu Software Center, run it and take your space back using the nice interface

[image]

and the easy to use resize partitions screen

[image]

Note that you need to do it from the LiveCD since you cannot resize a currently mounted partition. And of course has with all partition resizing operations you should back up at least your most important data, that goes almost without saying.